# How can I run a FOR /F command in a batch file to capture a path in a registry value

Tags: batch-file, registry

I need to get the registry value for HKLM\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Photoshop\12.0 data dtring ApplicationPath.  The value is a path statement such as C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS5.1 (64 Bit).  I am attempting to run a FOR /F loop to get this value anf set an echo %%X to display the value then set a variable called APPFOLDER to the return value of %%X.  Below is the code I am using.  The return value is getting truncated after C:\Program. It does not display the entire path because there is a space between C:\Program and Files.  How can I get around this problem and capture the entire path for ApplicationPath value?

The variable LINES is the number of line the REG Query command displays in XP or Windows 7.  In Windows 7 it is 2 lines

```
rem set LINES=2
rem ver | FIND "5.1" && SET LINES=4
FOR /F "usebackq skip=%LINES% tokens=3*" %%X IN ('REG QUERY HKLM\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Photoshop\12.0 /v ApplicationPath') DO ( 
    echo %%X
    SET APPFOLDER=%%X
    )

rem Run the installer to remove Photoshop 12.1
if %APPFOLDER%="C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS5.1 (64 Bit)\"
    %SYSDIR%\msiexec.exe /uninstall {67A1C99B-8E97-41AF-97DF-DDDE24A84C01} /quiet
    )   Else   (
    %SYSDIR%\msiexec.exe /uninstall {5A430790-9605-48AF-B649-6A63B68863AE} /quiet
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `tokens=2,*` instead of `tokens=3*`,
as `3*` is the same as `3,*` you only got `C:\program` in %%X and the rest in %%Y.

With `tokens=2,*` you get `REG_SZ` in %%X and the rest in %%Y